# Setting value, key pair in Dictionary using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, dictionary

A simple script in the Google Earth Engine code editor,

```
var dict = ee.Dictionary();
dict.set('num', 10);
print(dict);
```

gives `Object (0 properties)` as the output

even when i do `print(dict.keys())` or `print(dict.values())` it throws empty list.

How do I pass a key,value pair to a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to assign your new dictionary to an existing or new variable:

```
var dict = ee.Dictionary();
dict = dict.set('num', 10);
print(dict);
```